# Git change base branch

Tags: git

I have a branch named "develop" and based on that branch I made another branch "TestFeature" .
And then I made other branch "NewFeature" based on TestFeature and made some changes and commited .

Problem is that I dont want the changes that are in TestFeature to be present in my NewFeature branch . I want it to be based on "develop" .

How can I do it ?

Comment: `git rebase --onto ...` Interestingly [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) has an example that is *very* close to what you describe. Did you not read it?

Comment: It worked . Thanks .

I did git rebase --onto develop TestFeature NewFeature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer.)

```
git rebase --onto ...
```

Interestingly [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) has an example that is very close to what you describe.